# Search and replace lines AFTER a regex match using "sed"

Tags: sed, regular-expression

This kind of feels like it would be easier in `awk`, but I'm curious if `sed` can do it. Here is my input:

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 1
line 2
line 3
```

I'd like to write an in-place regex that finds the second `line 1`, then replaces all `line 3`'s found after that. The output would look like this:

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 1
line 2
replaced
line 1
line 2
replaced
```

I'm not really looking for "clever" solutions that only apply to this input. I want to learn if there is a general-purpose way to search and replace *after* a match with `sed`.

I thought the solution would be somewhere in [the `addr` documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#sed-addresses), but it doesn't seem to describe `/starting point/,s/...` as something you can do, and I'm getting error when I attempt to do so.

Answer (score 2):

To do this, you need to count the number of times you've already seen the target line.
Unfortunately, counting anything in `sed` is a PITA.  You'd be better off doing this in `awk` or `perl`.  For example:

```
$ perl -p -e '$found++ if m/line 1/;
              next if $found < 2;
              s/line 3/replaced/' input.txt 
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 1
line 2
replaced
line 1
line 2
replaced
```

or in `awk`:

```
$ awk '/line 1/ { found++ };
       found < 2 { print ; next };
       { sub(/line 3/,"replaced") ; print }' input.txt 
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 1
line 2
replaced
line 1
line 2
replaced
```

These work, but are far from optimal solutions, especially the `awk` version (which is just a direct translation of the perl).

BTW, it wouldn't be difficult at all to make either version take the regex to search for and **count**, the regex to search for and **replace**, the replacement string, and even the required count as command-line options instead of hard-coding them in the script.

Comment: What is m in the first line of perl ($found++ if m/line 1/)? thanks.

Comment: `m` is perl's match operator, similar to how `s` is perl's search and replace operator.   `m` is optional if you use `/` as the regex delimiter, but required if you use anything else (otherwise perl can't distinguish between a match operation or some random gibberish syntax error).   i.e.  `/line 1/` is the same as `m/line 1/`....but if you want to use `:` or `=` or `{}` or whatever, you need to write it as, e.g., `m:line 1:` or `m{line 1}`.   I prefer to use it whether it's required or not.  see `man perlop` and search for `m/PATTERN`

Comment: BTW, you can use pretty nearly anything you like as a regex delimiter (with some nice syntactic sugar like balanced curly braces)....but using `?` as the delimiter is handled specially.   `m?PATTERN?` is a match-once operator, it matches only on the first occurrence in a file (or until `reset` is called).  This is also described further on in `man perlop`.    `man perlre` is also worth reading.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU `sed` (for the 0 address¹):

```
$ sed '0,/^line 1$/b; /^line 1$/,$ s/^line 3$/replaced/' < file
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 1
line 2
replaced
line 1
line 2
replaced
```

We `b`ranch *out* for the first `0,/^line 1/` range, which means the second `/^line 1$/,$` only sees its starting line when reaching the second occurrence of `line 1`.

With `awk`, it's easier to spot the n<sup>th</sup> occurrence of `line 1`:

```
awk '$0 == "line 1" && ++n == 2, eof {if ($0 == "line 3") $0 = "replaced"}; 1'
```

(here `eof` is just any other uninitialised variable, so which yields *false* to signify that that *first*, *last* range has no end; same as just using `0` literally though more legible; similarly, we could use `!skip` instead of `1` to signify *true* for the current record to be printed but using `1` is idiomatic enough that it should be recognised by all `awk` users and a more  legible alternative would rather be `{print}`).

---

<sup>¹ and since we assume GNU `sed`, we can also add `;more commands` after the `b` one, which is not standard either. We'd need another `-e 'more commands'` with other `sed`s.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Create a counter in the buffer (pattern space) and check it on each line:

```
sed '
/^line 1/{x;/11/!s/^/1/;x}
x;/11/{x;b1};x;b
:1;s/^line 3$/replaced/
' file
```

we use `1` as the counter unit

[update] Better performance:

```
sed '
/^line 1$/{x;/11/!s/^/1/;x}
/^line 3$/!b
x;/11/!{x;b}
x;s/.*/replaced/
' file
```

The counter is checked only in the lines matching the pattern - `/^line 3$/`

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU `sed` specifically:

```bsh
sed -e '0,/^line 1$/ b' \
    -e '//,$ s/^line 3$/replaced/' file
```

This first outputs all lines between the start of the file and the first `line 1` line.  Using `0` as the start of an address range like this requires GNU `sed` and enables us to cope with the case where `line 1` is the very first line of the file.

After reaching the first `line 1` line and outputting it, it applies a substitution to all lines from the next `line 1` line to the end of the file, replacing the `line 3` lines with the text `replaced`.

If you want to insert multiple lines of text, use `c` (change) rather than `s` (substitute):

```bsh
sed -e '0,/^line 1$/ b' \
    -e '//,$ {' \
      -e '/^line 3$/ c\' \
      -e 'replace 1\' \
      -e 'replace 2' \
    -e '}' file
```

Each line, apart from the last that you want to replace the `line 3` lines with, must end with a backslash.

It may be easier to see what that `sed` script is doing if we write the script as a separate editing script:

```
0,/^line 1$/ b

//,$ {
        /^line 3$/ c\
replaced 1\
replaced 2
}
```

---

Using `ed`, we could find the first `line 1`, then perform a `c` (change) command on each line matching `line 3` from the next line matching `line 1` on to the end.

```
/^line 1$/; //,$ g/^line 3$/ c\
replaced
```

From the command line, sending the result to the terminal,

```bsh
ed -s file <<'END_ED'
/^line 1$/; //,$ g/^line 3$/ c\
replaced
,p
Q
END_ED
```

or,

```bsh
printf '%s\n' '/^line 1$/; //,$ g/^line 3$/ c\' 'replaced' ',p' 'Q' |
ed -s file
```

To replace the `line 3` lines with multiple lines of text, make sure that each line of text added is terminated by a backslash:

```bsh
ed -s file <<'END_ED'
/^line 1$/; //,$ g/^line 3$/ c\
replaced\
more replace text\
even more
,p
Q
END_ED
```

To do an in-place edit, use `w` (write the buffer to file) and `q` (quit) in place of `,p` (print all lines in the buffer) and `Q` (quit, unconditionally) in the editing script.

Note that `ed` is unsuitable for editing *huge* files, as the editor reads the file into memory.

---

If you only want to replace the lines with a single line of text, you could avoid a multi-line `ed` script by using `s` (substitute) in place of `c` (well, you need `,p` and `Q` too):

```
/^line 1$/; //,$ g/^line 3$/ s//replaced/
```

Testing:

```bsh
$ printf '%s\n' '/^line 1$/; //,$ g/^line 3$/ s//replaced/' ',p' 'Q' | ed -s file
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 1
line 2
replaced
line 1
line 2
replaced
```

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU sed we can perform the task
by storing the count as dots `.` in the hold
space.

```
sed -e '
  /^line 1$/,/^line 1$/{//!b
    x;s/^$/./;x;t
    :a;n;s/^line 3$/REPLACED/;ba
  }
' file
```

Another possibility without using the range
operator and with extended regex mode
in GNU sed. Here the newline `\n` function as counter, stored in the hold space.

```
sed -Ee '
  /^line 1$/H
  x;s/^(\n{1,2}).*/\1/;x
  /^line 3$/G
  /\n.{2}/c REPLACED
  s/\n//g
' file
```

---

Perl can do the same in a similar fashion

```
perl -lpe '
  s/^line 3$/$a?"REPLACED":$&/e
           unless
  m?^line 1$? ... /^line 1$(?{$a++})/;
' file
```

---

Using awk, we can nicely combine regexes
with variables and incrementing by one

```
awk '
1 < ( k += /^line 1$/ ) &&
sub(/^line 3$/,"REPLACED") ||
1' file
```